# Fallout 4 - Lost voices when talking to follower/characters

Tags: fallout-4

I have Fallout 4 on my Xbox One. Up until now everything has been fine, however now when I try to talk to people I cannot hear their voices at all unless I face away, which I can't do when "chatting" to follower etc.

I've deleted the game, reinstalled it, tried a new save, tried loading an old save... The issue remains.

I'm totally stuck. Has anyone come across this/fixed this?

Comment: I don't own an Xbox One, but does deleting the game also delete all patches/updates to the games as well? It seems like one of those could be an issue.

Comment: As far as i'm aware it does. Just doesn't make sense because it's been absolutely fine since i got it. Only playing up now :/

Comment: I'd just be curious if it auto-updated something causing it to break. I wouldn't see another good reason unless some issue cropped up on your console. Does sound work fine in other games or elsewhere in the game?

Comment: Literally EVERYTHING works fine apart from dialogue/chats with other players. The only update was done at the point of install, been nothing since. Worked last night, doesn't work this afternoon

Comment: this sounds kind of like a problem with the center channel. Check your audio cables and ensure the console/tv/audio chain is set up for surround or stereo all the way through.

Comment: I have no surround sound which is whats puzzling me about this. It's just the usual 2 speaker system in the tv. Havent changed anything. I'll dig around though :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay so this is a real simple one... Where I had changed the input type from auto-detect to HDMI, it automatically changed the sound type to a version of surround sound. I just changed this back to stereo and all is right with the world.

Annoying i wasted 3 hours sorting this but hey! lol